# Where do I put typescript definitions and how do i write them when the object already has a definition

Tags: typescript

I'm sorry for this question, because I know the answer has to exist somewhere, but I don't think i have a deep enough understanding of Typescript to even know what I'm supposed to be searching for.

My problem is that I have added a jquery plugin called `typeahead` as well as a global variable on the window object named `bound` which is for communicating to my c# wrapper app.

These items are causing errors when I compile, and I want to get rid of the errors, so what am I supposed to do?  I thought maybe I'm supposed to created definitions for these items, but I can't find any documentation for how to do that, since `jquery` already has a definition, because I installed the `jquery` definition from `typings`, and it appears maybe the `window` object already has a definition as well.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Property 'typeahead' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
Property 'bound' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

So, what do I do to make the errors stop?  If i'm supposed to write definitions, where do the definitions go, and how do I write definitions for objects that already have definitions?

I tried making a file in the root of my project called `index.d.ts`, but as soon as I created that file, with no code in it, i got this error:

```
WARNING in ./src/index.d.ts
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Output generation failed
```

I tried adding interface statements, module declaration statements, and namespace declaration statements, and nothing can make the error go away.  Is the filename wrong?  Is the file supposed to be in a certain location?

I've read the documenation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html
But I can't see anything about where the definition go, or how to write definitions for objects that already exist.

thanks in advance for any help anyone can give.

*EDIT*

Definitely Typed, nor Typings contain definitions for the typeahead library I'm using, nor for the global `bound` object i created.  I need to understand how to manually get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the definitions for typeahead from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts), and then you can add it to whichever files are using it this:

```
/// <reference path="./pathFromFile/typeahead.d.ts" />
```

If you want to create or extend definitions for a JS library, you'll have to create .d.ts file that can go anywhere as long as your reference path is correct. I use [this guide](http://peter.grman.at/how-to-write-typescript-definition-files/) which was pretty helpful for me.

Comment: DefinitelyTyped doesn't have definitions for the typeahead library I'm using, nor does it have definitions for the global `bound` object I created.

Comment: Which version of typeahead are you using, or do you need a customized definitions file? The link I put is to 0.11.1. As far as declaring global objects, TypeScript 1.8 added in [augmenting the global scope](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules), which sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using a library called bootstrap-3-typeahead, version 4.0.1.  The link you put is for a library called "Twitter Typeahead".

Comment: The DefinitelyTyped link you posted is not relevant since the library I'm using is not there, but that guide link you posted is *exactly* what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: The blogger lost me at:

"But when TypeScript came out - wow, so amazing, almost like C# or Java!"